# Is there a way to order my products page by in stock first and out of stock at the end of the page?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I am new to laravel and I am trying to build an ecommerce website, and I was wondering if there is a way to sort my products page by in stock first then out of stock rather than hiding them. In other orders can I get Products from DB based on $quantity?

Comment: ->orderBy('quantity') - simple.

Comment: How do you save stock info in your database? column name, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply  get all of your orders in descending order as per quantity  of items in stocks.

DB::table('Products ')->orderByDesc('quantity ')->get();